# How to delete item from listview using own ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I Have problem, I want to delete a row frow listView and this element from ArrayList.

This is my new ArrayAdapter

```
private ExpenditureAdapter adapter = null;
```

and I adding to it data using:

```
adapter = new ExpenditureAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_show_list,addExpenditure.getExpidentures());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

It works correctly, but I want create `OnItemClickListener` and use it to delete data from `listView` and from `ArrayList<Expenditure>`, but how to do it ?

My effort:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                addExpenditure.getExpidentures().remove();
            }
        });
```

But ofc it doesn't work.How get index to delete this ?

Comment: show your effort please...

Comment: Remove the item from your arraylist then notify the arrayadapter(notifydatasetchanged)

Comment: position is the index of the selected item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 YourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
            long arg3) 
      {
              YourArrayList.remove(position);
            YourArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
   });
```

Comment: But how create Listener on Click ?

Comment: you have to create onitemclicklistener not onclicklistener for the listview

Comment: Almost, now I have problem with listView = (ListView)findViewById(); i  have this error    Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: If you are using ListActivity your xml file must specify the keyword android while mentioning to a ID

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it working, change your listener to this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         addExpenditure.getExpidentures().remove(position);
         parent.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
});
```

Basically, if you are changing the underlying data of an adapter (your ArrayList), you need to notify the adapter so it can update the list accordingly. This will remove the item and then redraw the list.